# Getting function used to create coroutine/thread in Lua

Tags: lua, coroutine

Is it possible to get the original function used to create a coroutine ?

```
thread = coroutine.create(function()
   -- Code
end)

f = get_function_from_thread(thread)
```

Comment: Give your anonymous function a name so you can refer to it later. Then refer to the function through that name when you `coroutine.create` it. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: I have some functions which contain upvalues (created in another function in another module). The function I am writing receives coroutines/threads, but I would like to access the upvalues stored in the original function

Comment: Something like `debug.getlocal` and `debug.get(set)upvalue` might help using those debug functions like this is a code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this out-of-the box, but you can always redefine `coroutine.create`:

```
local create=coroutine.create
local created={}

function coroutine.create(f)
   local t=create(f)
   created[t]=f
   return t
end

function get_function_from_thread(t)
   return created[t]
end
```

If you create lots of coroutines, consider setting `created` as a weak table.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you *can* do this out-of-the-box using `debug.getinfo`, but only **if the coroutine is in a yield or running state**.

```lua
func = function () for i = 1, 4 do coroutine.yield(4) end end
co = coroutine.create(func)

assert(debug.getinfo(co, 1) == nil, "must have resumed at least once")

coroutine.resume(co)

assert(debug.getinfo(co, 1).func == func, 
    "getinfo can get the func from its stack")

while coroutine.status(co) ~= "dead" do coroutine.resume(co) end

assert(debug.getinfo(co, 1) == nil, "its stack is gone after returning")
```

Confirmed working with Lua 5.1 and LuaJIT 2.1.0.